# Using Go, how should I access window components in traditional inheritance based GUI Frameworks?

Tags: design-patterns, user-interface, go, gtk, go-gtk

I am doing some experimental work using [**GTK bindings for Go**](https://github.com/mattn/go-gtk).

As with most GUI frameworks, a GTK GUI app generally spawns a main window and the application's work is done within the context of that window.

When you write a GTK GUI app in C++, you inherit from the framework window class - `gtk.Window` - and declare the other GUI components for your app as public members of your inherited window class (or use public access methods in your window class). That way they can be manipulated by a window controller class. which addresses them by name as members of your window class.  You simply pass a pointer to your main window into the controller class and manipulate its members by writing `mWindow.MyWidget.text="text"`, etc. Again, AFAIK, most GUI applications are designed similarly, regardless of the GUI framework being used.

However, since Go does not support inheritance, this option is not possible: When you instantiate additional GUI components in a Go-Gtk window, they are self standing variables, not members of the parent window class - they don't "live" in a container class. This means that your GUI controller class would have to access each component in the main window individually, with no cohesive structure or single reference to refer to. This compromises readability and good code organization, IMO - forces your code to be somewhat poorly structured.

I believe the solution to this problem in Go would be to declare a struct/interface that will serve as a container for all the main window's GUI components. That interface would publish access methods for the components and could be passed to a GUI controller unit for manipulating its members.

I need to know if there is a standard idiomatic Go design pattern for such a task, or what would be considered the correct approach to this issue using Go.

*I understand that `Go` is designed to be a systems programming language, not really designed with frontEnd development in mind, but I have heard it said that "every good systems language will end up being used for applications", and there is no better systems language out there today than `Go` - the proof is that many Go bindings for GUI frameworks and other application tasks are surfacing. Look no further than [**A list of Go projects.**](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Projects)*

***I guess the takeaway from all this is that Go is not designed to make it easy to develop desktop GUI apps, which are a dying breed***.

Comment: Go supports something similar to inheritance: [embedding](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#embedding) - checkout the struct embedding especially - maybe that helps (I have no knowledge about go-gtk).

Comment: @ZeissS - I know about type embedding, haven't thought about in this context - maybe... Tnx.  Go-GTK is just a Go binding for the plain vanilla GTK+ , and AFAIK, the issue would not only be with GTK, but essentially with any GUI framework that works using the model I outlined in the question-inheritance based - which means all of the well known ones. –

Comment: @ZeissS - I don't believe type embedding will help here, because there is no container to embed. Once there is a container, it might work nicely. Type embedding is really not at all similar to inheritance, although it **looks like it** in some ways. As I understand it, it's simply syntactical sugar for delegation.

Comment: The `event` example at https://github.com/mattn/go-gtk/blob/master/example/event/event.go uses `channels` to send window events to an infinite for loop with a type-switch in it to determine the event type. Seems like a good solution, although maybe separate channels for different events sending to a `select` may be more idiomatic.

Comment: @Intermernet - that sounds like an interesting, although roundabout approach. I will check that out as well. Fact is, I am getting discouraged. It's clear that Go was not designed to handle general application development. It's a specialized language designed for parallel server side work (no big surprise there since it's started at Google) and its restriction make it difficult to use for other tasks, outside of console apps and certain types of web development, from what I have seen. Frankly, I can't believe, after all I've read, that checking error codes is how Go handles errors.

Comment: I'd recommend having a look at http://swtch.com/~rsc/thread/cws.pdf . It's a paper written by Rob Pike about Newsqueak (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newsqueak) which is a direct ancestor of Go, and was originally designed for graphical systems. It discusses some of the ways to re-think graphical systems programming in ways that allow greater concurrency, and therefore less locking. Most of this is directly applicable to graphical application design in Go today.

Comment: @Intermernet - I am running and playing with `event.go` right now - perhaps that is the way to do it. Why not post an answer - I will certainly give you an upvote and if I can use that engine to do what I need, you'll get the bounty.

Comment: "I guess the takeaway from all this is that Go is not designed to make it easy to develop desktop GUI apps, which are a dying breed."...

I'd say that your statement is a sweeping one based on accessing a GUI toolkit built for a different language. I would recommend trying a Go toolkit instead, which will integrate much better with the Go language! Try https://fyne.io or https://gioui.org for something more up to date than GTK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're asking how one might group a set of things into a collection, such that a controller can access all of them. You note that in C++, one would make this collection a subclass of gtk.Window. In go, there's no classes or type hierarchies, but otherwise the solutions are similar.

The solution is just to define a struct. Perhaps something like this:

```
type MainWindow struct {
    Win         *gtk.Window
    RedButton   *gtk.Widget
    GreenButton *gtk.Widget
}
```

A controller for the window can access any of the fields, without additional methods or accessors being needed:

```
type MainController struct {
    W *MainWindow
    other fields...
}

func (mc *MainController) DoSomething() {
    mc.W.RedButton.MakeVisible(true)
    mc.W.GreenButton.MakeVisible(false)
}
```

The methods here are just for illustration, obviously.

Comment: That is exactly the approach I tried. Unfortunately, since Go doesn't support any form of inheritance or traditional polymorphism, each widget has to be declared and accessed specifically with its type so you can't declare generic event handlers. (That's really a different question though). Also, Go's obsession with  orthogonality makes it difficult to break up the code into separate modules because of cross dependencies. For example, if the package that initializes the mainWindow and widgets publishes your struct for a controller package, which will define event handlers for the widgets...

Comment: _Continued_ - ... you get cross dependencies. I figured no problem - I'll define a third package for that, that uses both of the others - but again I ran into cross dependency issues. Frankly, I didn't have the patience to work it out, because I concluded this is obviously something Go was not meant to do. Go does not support inheritance, so using frameworks that assume inheritance such as we have in C++ or Java or Python, is just "going against the grain".

Comment: _Continued -_ **Having said all that:** Since you've properly understood the question and taken the effort to think it through and post a viable answer given the parameters of the question, I'm awarding you the bounty.

Answer (score 2):

If I had to write an application with a GUI in Go, i would completely decouple the GUI part from the application part.  An example of such approach is the  [GTK Server](http://www.gtk-server.org).

Only, you don't need a separate process to handle the GUI: you can do that in a goroutine, that communicates with the rest of the application using channels,  the same way the Gtk Server uses sockets/pipes/message queues.

I don't know of anybody who used this approach, and I used it myself only in a  toy program that builds a mimimalistic Tk GUI (used Tk because has a built-in interpreter and didn't know yet of gtk-server).  But this would be for  me  the  idiomatic way to build a GUI application in Go.

Comment: Will take a look GTKServer. But my app may be different than a server app, which does not have to deal directly with a GUI-I'm dealing with the sort of application that has to manipulate the GUI. For example, user enters numerical values into SpinBox controls, I send the values to a calculation module that generates a Fibonacci series and returns a slice containing the series. Then I display the slice in a control-so my controller package,sitting between the GUI and the calculation module, has access GUI controls and event handlers. (I should not talk until I look at your example)

Comment: It's really not a question about GUI's but a question about how in Go to deal with a framework that depends on inheritance for appropriate use without writing a lot of highly coupled, ugly looking code. I'm just taking GUI's as an example because the well known frameworks, generally being C/C++ based, all expect you to use inheritance along the lines I outlined - and I personally prefer GTK for GUI work on Linux. Advantages of Go are so great that I am hooked, but no inheritance at all, combined with very strict rules about cyclical dependencies, makes one think very differently about design.

Comment: (continued) I would like to see **one level** of inheritance allowed in Go. Inheritance is overrated and often abused, but when used properly, it is a very powerful feature that greatly facilitates good design. In all my years of OOP development (over 20) I can count on one hand the number of times I have used more than one level of inheritance. One level of inheritance in the case I illustrated would completely eliminate the problem.

Comment: IMO the lack of any support for inheritance, and abandonment of the long accepted and highly advantageous exception model for dealing with errors are regressions and are causing me serious doubts about continuing with Go. To revert to checking error codes after 20 years of advancements in software technology is ludicrious IMO.